# Undefined symbol when I build an installed cocoa pod of Mediation Test Suite

Tags: ios, xcode, admob, google-ads-api

We are trying to implement the Mediation Test Suite but, we are getting the following error message:

> Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:   "_kGADSimulatorID",
> referenced from:
> _GMTSMediationRequest in GoogleMobileAdsMediationTestSuite(GMTSMediationHelper.o)
> "_kGADAdSizeBanner", referenced from:
> -[GMTSBannerAdLoader initWithAdUnitId:rootViewController:] in GoogleMobileAdsMediationTestSuite(GMTSBannerAdLoader.o)
> "_kGADAdLoaderAdTypeNative", referenced from:
> -[GMTSNativeAdLoader initWithAdUnitId:rootViewController:] in GoogleMobileAdsMediationTestSuite(GMTSNativeAdLoader.o) ld: symbol(s)
> not found for architecture arm64 clang: error: linker command failed
> with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 0):

GoogleMobileAdsMediationTestSuite 2.0 incompatible with latest AdMob. Remove it or update to 3.0